# Conda Environments: how to ask the system the possible available Environments

Tags: virtualenv, conda, environment, virtual-environment

Some weeks ago I created a `conda` environment for some old purposes. Now I need again the same environment but I do not remember the name I have used.

**Question**: Is there a way of asking the system "which environment do you have available"?

I am sure that I can found the one I am looking for because I normally use meaningful names. I have also used

```
history | grep conda
```

but there are no results. I suppose because XUbuntu deletes, periodically, the history of the terminal, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all environments

```
conda info --envs
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I found:

```
conda env list
```

It works properly as an alternative to the already proposed:

```
conda info --envs
```